# Connecting Arduino to wunderground using ESP8266

Tags: json, arduino, esp8266

I'm trying to use an ESP8266 and Arduino Uno to connect to wunderground and get the JSON file to get the current weather. With my code I am connecting to the server fine. What seems to be the issue is that it's not giving me the whole return file.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

SoftwareSerial esp8266(8, 9);
bool flag = true;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (flag) {
    String cmd;
    int length;
    cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
    cmd += "api.wunderground.com";
    cmd += "\",80";
    esp8266.println(cmd);
    Serial.println(cmd);
    delay(2000);
    Serial.write(esp8266.read());
    if (esp8266.find("CONNECT")) {
      Serial.println("CONNECT found so your connected");
    }
    String action;
    action = "GET http://api.wunderground.com/api/APIKEY/conditions/q/Canada/Regina.json HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    length = action.length();
    cmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
    cmd += length;
    esp8266.println(cmd);
    Serial.println(cmd);
    delay(5000);
    if (esp8266.find(">")) {
      Serial.print(">");
    } else {
      esp8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
      Serial.println(F("connect timeout"));
    }

    esp8266.println(action);
    Serial.println(action);
    delay(700);

    String test = "";
    while (esp8266.available()) {
      char c = esp8266.read();
      test += c;
    }
    Serial.println(test);
    flag = false;
    Serial.println("Flag is false");
  }
}
```

Running this code give me the following result:

> AT+CIPSTART="TCP","api.wunderground.com",80
>       ACONNECT found so your connected
>       AT+CIPSEND=97
>   GET http://api.wunderground.com/api/7287eb3ace065563/conditions/q/Canada/Regina.json HTTP/1.0
>
> busy s...
>
> Recv 97 bytes
>
> SEND OK
>
> +IPD,1460:HTTP/1.0:"0.1",
>         "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
>         "
>       Flag is false

As you can see I only get a snippet of the JSON file. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not sending JSON at all. It detected that your Arduino/ESP combo was not a human, and is scolding you, letting you know that you are in breach of the Terms of Service, as described in http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html. You need to set some headers, to masquerade as a browser and thus pass as a human user.

Comment: After I asked this I came across something like what you mentioned someone had to set more headers. I will have to look into this a bit more. Are there particular headers that you know of that I would have to set?

Comment: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending The one you want is USER_AGENT.